# Laravel using web authentication in all api routes redirect to home

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, authorization

i want to use web authentication for all api routes. I created middleware and this is how it looks like

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web'], 'prefix' => 'v1',], function ($router) {
   Route::apiResource('subscriptions', 'Api\SubscriptionController');
   Route::post('subscriptions/{id}/resend', 'Api\SubscriptionController@resend')->name('resend');
   Route::post('subscriptions/{id}/grace', 'Api\SubscriptionController@addGrace')->name('grace');
   Route::apiResource('accounts', 'Api\SocialMediaAccountController');
   Route::post('accounts/{id}/reset', 'Api\SocialMediaAccountController@reset');
Route::apiResource('customers', 'Api\CustomerController');
});
```

When i am already logged in and i try to make request to api route, it redirect me to the home page. How can i fix this ?

Here is the config/auth.php

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

I don't want api routes to be redirected if i am already logged in. I just want to do web authorization and continue with same request.

Comment: `I don't want api routes to be redirected. I just want to do web authorization and continue with same request.`  If you aren't authenticated then how do you want this to work?

Comment: That's the expected behavior. You should login first before accessing the protected routes. If you expect something else, maybe you should not use `auth:web` middleware.

Comment: @Devon I forgot to mention that i am already logged in when i open api/v1/subscription in web browser. It is get request so it should list me all my subscriptions but it redirect me instead.

Comment: @YohanesGultom forgot to mention that i am already logged in.

Comment: Any reason to not use `auth:api` middleware for protected api routes?

Comment: @linktoahref okey i will give it a try. And update you. Thank you

Comment: what middleware did you "create"?

Answer (score 11):

Just two updates to restrict your api routes to require your web auth session to make api requests.

1. Update middleware from `api` to `web`.

```php
# File: app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('web') # <-- CHANGE to 'web'
             ->namespace($this->namespace."\\API")
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

    }
```

2. Update middleware from `auth:api` to `auth:web` (or simply `auth`)

```php
# routes/api.php
Route::middleware('auth:web')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->user();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few differences between web and api routes in Laravel.  The biggest difference being the middleware included  by default.

You can see the differences between the middleware groups in app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

APIs are supposed to be stateless so cookies and sessions are not set up.  Since the api routes do not start the session, you won't have your authenticated session available.

You could set your routes to use the 'web' group, or see about consuming your own API via Javascript: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript.