# Logged in with web route but can not authenticated with api route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Duplicated: [Laravel using web authentication in all api routes redirect to home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166907/laravel-using-web-authentication-in-all-api-routes-redirect-to-home)

I don't know the keyword to search it on google so sorry about something stupid. I use web route to load view and api route to load json data like this:

- `/shop/categories`
- `/api/shop/categories`

I logged in with web route and auth middleware check is okay, I can get user name by auth()->user()->name. But when I call jquery ajax with /api/shop/categories I get an error "Authenticated.", I try to add middleware auth:api but nothing change. I read document and I see I must include api_token url.

How do I use the api when logged in with web route, middleware check?

Here is my some code:

```
//web route
Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix, 'middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('categories', 'CategoryController@getView')->name('category_get_view');
});

// api route
Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix, 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
    Route::get('categories', 'CategoryController@getJson');
    Route::get('categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@getDetail');
    Route::put('categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@putSave');
    Route::post('categories', 'CategoryController@postSave');
    Route::delete('categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@deleteSave');
});

// dd($request)
Request {#42
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#399
    class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
    this: AuthServiceProvider {#32 …}
    parameters: {
      $guard: {
        default: null
      }
    }
    use: {
      $app: Application {#2 …}
    }
    file: "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider.php"
    line: "85 to 87"
  }
  #routeResolver: Closure {#412
    class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
    this: Router {#25 …}
    use: {
      $route: Route {#181 …}
    }
    file: "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php"
    line: "649 to 651"
  }
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#44
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: ParameterBag {#50
    #parameters: array:2 [
      "key" => null
      "page" => "1"
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#50}
  +server: ServerBag {#46
    #parameters: array:40 [
      "REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "backend.local"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "*/*"
      "HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN" => "BNlGYoppmtl7fljKeQ4TGdNmbGoiuKWTeoLDbKln"
      "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" => "XMLHttpRequest"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://backend.local/shop/categories"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_COOKIE" => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNcL0t5aEMxZHNBM2wrNkRvc0RCUUlBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InlaTUlLdSt4UXVmdktNZk81ZzNpMWFNQUVqalZZTmNsRmpcLzZiQkkrdTRZZEphODVPYU5qYXdiSkRVMUUra0hJIiwibWFjIjoiMTdlNjUzYmVkYWRiM2JiNDNlMWYzMjQ1MmM0ZmIxMjQ0YzczOWE4NjQ2N2UzNzZmOTkxOGYxYTJjOTE5MmU0NiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InpLOUw5SHR6S0RWU21lSEhZMWVEZHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN1hNZUlNWUJacm83bEdFd3pCR0R1R1d1UVZZdmRcL3g3aXQ3QlhQOHNZZXFJUGVqOFBXS2dKZVFvYjl3NGZoRUsiLCJtYWMiOiI1ZjNhZmFjM2Q1ZjlmYzUwZmQ3ODA0MTJkZGNiMzdlZDhjYTljODViMTY0MTE5ZDA0YTg0ZTJkY2EwYjJmOWJmIn0%3D"
      "PATH" => ""
      "SystemRoot" => "C:\WINDOWS"
      "COMSPEC" => "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
      "PATHEXT" => ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"
      "WINDIR" => "C:\WINDOWS"
      "SERVER_SIGNATURE" => "<address>Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18 Server at backend.local Port 80</address>\n"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "backend.local"
      "SERVER_ADDR" => "::1"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "80"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "::1"
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "/public"
      "REQUEST_SCHEME" => "http"
      "CONTEXT_PREFIX" => ""
      "CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "/public"
      "SERVER_ADMIN" => "wampserver@wampserver.invalid"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "/public/index.php"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "64525"
      "REDIRECT_URL" => "/api/shop/categories"
      "REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING" => "key=&page=1"
      "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => "CGI/1.1"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
      "QUERY_STRING" => "key=&page=1"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/api/shop/categories?key=&page=1"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
      "PHP_SELF" => "/index.php"
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1570505297.533
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1570505297
    ]
  }
  +files: FileBag {#47
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#45
    #parameters: array:2 [
      "XSRF-TOKEN" => "eyJpdiI6IjNcL0t5aEMxZHNBM2wrNkRvc0RCUUlBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InlaTUlLdSt4UXVmdktNZk81ZzNpMWFNQUVqalZZTmNsRmpcLzZiQkkrdTRZZEphODVPYU5qYXdiSkRVMUUra0hJIiwibWFjIjoiMTdlNjUzYmVkYWRiM2JiNDNlMWYzMjQ1MmM0ZmIxMjQ0YzczOWE4NjQ2N2UzNzZmOTkxOGYxYTJjOTE5MmU0NiJ9"
      "laravel_session" => "eyJpdiI6InpLOUw5SHR6S0RWU21lSEhZMWVEZHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN1hNZUlNWUJacm83bEdFd3pCR0R1R1d1UVZZdmRcL3g3aXQ3QlhQOHNZZXFJUGVqOFBXS2dKZVFvYjl3NGZoRUsiLCJtYWMiOiI1ZjNhZmFjM2Q1ZjlmYzUwZmQ3ODA0MTJkZGNiMzdlZDhjYTljODViMTY0MTE5ZDA0YTg0ZTJkY2EwYjJmOWJmIn0="
    ]
  }
  +headers: HeaderBag {#48
    #headers: array:10 [
      "host" => array:1 [
        0 => "backend.local"
      ]
      "connection" => array:1 [
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
      "accept" => array:1 [
        0 => "*/*"
      ]
      "x-csrf-token" => array:1 [
        0 => "BNlGYoppmtl7fljKeQ4TGdNmbGoiuKWTeoLDbKln"
      ]
      "x-requested-with" => array:1 [
        0 => "XMLHttpRequest"
      ]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [
        0 => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
      ]
      "referer" => array:1 [
        0 => "http://backend.local/shop/categories"
      ]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
        0 => "gzip, deflate"
      ]
      "accept-language" => array:1 [
        0 => "en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8"
      ]
      "cookie" => array:1 [
        0 => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNcL0t5aEMxZHNBM2wrNkRvc0RCUUlBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InlaTUlLdSt4UXVmdktNZk81ZzNpMWFNQUVqalZZTmNsRmpcLzZiQkkrdTRZZEphODVPYU5qYXdiSkRVMUUra0hJIiwibWFjIjoiMTdlNjUzYmVkYWRiM2JiNDNlMWYzMjQ1MmM0ZmIxMjQ0YzczOWE4NjQ2N2UzNzZmOTkxOGYxYTJjOTE5MmU0NiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InpLOUw5SHR6S0RWU21lSEhZMWVEZHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN1hNZUlNWUJacm83bEdFd3pCR0R1R1d1UVZZdmRcL3g3aXQ3QlhQOHNZZXFJUGVqOFBXS2dKZVFvYjl3NGZoRUsiLCJtYWMiOiI1ZjNhZmFjM2Q1ZjlmYzUwZmQ3ODA0MTJkZGNiMzdlZDhjYTljODViMTY0MTE5ZDA0YTg0ZTJkY2EwYjJmOWJmIn0%3D"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/api/shop/categories"
  #requestUri: "/api/shop/categories?key=&page=1"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: null
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

Comment: You must need to add your API routes in the `api.php`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing Authorization in your request's header..

Comment: i say no, just change middleware api to web in RouteServiceProvider.php

Comment: I have done that but still I am getting the null .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data from authenticated users but want it from the api authenticated. You should get it using `auth('guard-name')`

Comment: i'm only change middleware from api to web and it worked